# AppDelegate NIDAction

Tags: xamarin

When I add the following override to the AppDelegate:

```
public override void HandleAction(UIApplication application, string actionIdentifier, NSDictionary remoteNotificationInfo, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDAction))] Action completionHandler)
{
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0246 The type or namespace name 'NIDAction' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Notifi.iOS
>   C:\development\notifi\Notifi\Notifi\Notifi.iOS\AppDelegate.cs 119
>   Active

I've tried searching for information about NIDAction, but I can't find anything helpful - can I remove this attribute?

Comment: Same problem here. BlockProxy with NIDAction gets auto-added to the completion handler, but compiler does not know the type NIDAction. Did you find out anything about that since?

Comment: Same problem with [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity1V19))]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for you to annotate types when Xamarin [already does it](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.HandleAction/p/UIKit.UIApplication/System.String/UIKit.UILocalNotification/System.Action/) in a signature of every native call.

Just do this:

```
public override void HandleAction (UIApplication application, string actionIdentifier, NSDictionary remoteNotificationInfo, Action completionHandler)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: iccthedral thanks for the response - the annotation was added automatically by visual studio's code completion.  I figured it was safe to remove, but I was curious about what the attribute does.

Comment: Ah ok, I get u. It's most likely internal to Xamarin.iOS assembly. 
Perhaps you could find more about it if you'd to browse that assembly.